# problem with Fastcgi on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, fastcgi

iam a starter in using apache. i donno even how to setup apache.   can some one give me some links to all the steps to setup fastCGI on ubuntu?

Comment: check this link at ubuntu geek
http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-apache2-webserver-with-phpcgi-and-perl-support-in-ubuntu-server.html

Answer (score 0):

See http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html

Also if you're new to apache check out the documentation for your version:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu follow this guide:
[apache2 with mod_fcgid and php5](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-apache2-with-mod_fcgid-and-php5-on-ubuntu-8.10)